# Question on greatest integer function.

Tags: functions

If $ y = [2x-1] = 3[x-6] $

Find the possible values of $ [3x+y] $.

My attempt :

$y = [2x]-1 = 3[x]-18 $.

Now I don't understand what to do with [2x] as I can't take 2 out of the greatest integer function. I tried writing x = [x] + {x} but that does not work.

Pls help me.

Comment: @SakethMalyala it is.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE oops just realized

Comment: Is it clear now, @Md Masood?

Answer (score 2):

Try to write $x = [x] + \{x\}$, where $0\le\{x\}<1$ is the "fractional part" of $x$.

So, you'll have $[2x-1] = [2[x] + 2\{x\}-1] = 2[x]-1+ [2\{x\}]$,

and $3[x-6] = 3[[x] + \{x\} -6] = 3[x] -18+ 3[\{x\}] = 3[x] -18$.

Now you can consider the cases $[2\{x\}] = 0$ or $1$.